# QFtp Get never emits commandFinished()

Tags: qt, ftp, qftp

I am currently facing a weird problem concerning QFtp. I want to download a bunch of files from a FTP server but when I come to some point, after downloading x files on y, the `ftp->get()` command is done, the file is filled, but there is no emission of the `SIGNAL` `commandFinished()` and thus it does not download the other files.

Here is my code :

```
void Ftp::commandFinished(int i, bool error)
{

    if(ftp->currentCommand() == QFtp::Get)
    {
        if(error)
        {
            //blablabla-ERROR-blablabla
        }
        currentFile->close();
        filesToDownload.pop_front();
        processFileList();
    }

    /**Gestion de la commande Login (authentification de l'utilisateur)
    */
    if(ftp->currentCommand() == QFtp::Login)
    {//not utile here}

    /**Gestion de la commande ConnectToHost (connexion au serveur)
    */
    if (ftp->currentCommand() == QFtp::ConnectToHost) 
    {//not utile here}

    /**Gestion de la commande List (téléchargement d'un fichier)
    */
    if(ftp->currentCommand() == QFtp::List)
    {
        if(error)
        {
            //Nananana-FAIL-nanana
        }

        //!Tri des fichiers à télécharger en fonction de leur dernière date de modification
        if (!filesToDownload.isEmpty())
        {
            currentPeripheral->setLastDownloadDate(newLastModifiedDate) ;
            std::sort(filesToDownload.begin(),filesToDownload.end(),compareQUrlInfos);
            processFileList();
        }



    }
}

void Ftp::processFileList()
{

QUrlInfo info;

if (filesToDownload.isEmpty())
{
    //!Suicide de l'instance de Ftp
    ftp->close();
    disconnect(this,0,0,0);
    this->deleteLater();
    return ;
}

info = filesToDownload.first();
QDir dlDir(QString::number(currentPeripheral->getId()));

//!Si un fichier a été téléchargé, on déclenche son traitement
if (currentFile != nullptr)
{
    emit(oneDownloadFinished(currentFile->fileName(),currentPeripheral));
    delete currentFile;
    currentFile = nullptr;
}

//!On crée un répertoire de téléchargement si nécessaire
if (!dlDir.exists())
{
    dlDir.mkdir(".");
}

//!on crée le fichier qui contiendra le téléchargement
currentFile = new QFile(dlDir.filePath(info.name()));

if(!currentFile->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
{
    delete currentFile;
    currentFile = nullptr;
    emit(writeToMonitoringConsole(QString("Erreur lors de la creation du fichier "+info.name()),"Error"));
    return;
}


//Here I start (sometimes) a never ending fail
ftp->get(info.name(), currentFile);
}
```

At first I thought it was because I was making too much request and that I was rejected because of that, but even with a `Sleep(2000)` it blocks. The blocking appears even more quickly. I usually can download around 30 files (when lucky 70, once I managed to have 200 !). With `Sleep(2000)` I barely succed to download 2-3 files.

Is it a mistake from me ? Is there a limitation in QFtp I didn't found ? Or something else ?

**EDIT :** I tested somes things since I posted it, and what was striking, when monitoring the dataTransferProgress() signal, is that the problematic file is fully downloaded (qDebug says "88928/88928") but I never enter commandFinished().

My slot commandFinished() is linked to my QFtp::commandFinished SIGNAL this way :

```
connect(ftp, SIGNAL(commandFinished(int,bool)), this, SLOT(commandFinished(int,bool)));
```

Comment: I do not see any commandFinished signal in your code? Could you please share more code?

Comment: commandFinished() is emitted by the QFtp when one of the commands is done, I normaly should not send this signal myself.

[Qt commmandFinished](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qftp.html#commandFinished)

Comment: This might be https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-19409

Answer (score 3):

I'm seeing pretty much the same thing, with an `FTPWidget` class I use never receiving a `commandFinished` for a GET request. The dataTransferProgress() signal reliably reports 100% downloaded and its all there.

I've hacked around using a setting a timeout as follows:

```
// Set up a single shot QTimer and connect it to a function to fix things

connect(m_lostFinishedTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(lostFinishedHack()));

// Start the timeout when the download data progress hits 100%

void FtpWidget::updateXferProgress(qint64 readBytes, qint64 totalBytes)
{
    m_progressBar->setValue(progress_value(readBytes, totalBytes));

    if (m_downloading && readBytes == totalBytes)
        m_lostFinishedTimer->start();
}

// And don't forget to stop the timer if you do get a finish:

void FtpWidget::commandFinished(int id, bool error)
{
    QFtp::Command cmd = m_ftp->currentCommand();
    // ...
    if (cmd == QFtp::Get) 
    {
        m_lostFinishedTimer->stop();
        //....
    }
    // ...
}
```

where the timer is connected to a fixup routine basically close the download file, reconnect the server, and move on to the next file

```
void FtpWidget::lostFinishedHack()
{
    if (!m_downloading)
        return;

    if (m_downloadFile)
    {
        DOUT("FtpWidget::lostFinshedHack() -- file: " << DS(m_downloadFile->fileName()) << "\n");
        m_downloadFile->close();
        delete m_downloadFile;
        m_downloadFile = 0;
    }

    // just reconnect the thing
    Connect(m_ftpServerName->text());

    downloadNextFile();
}
```

This seems to work well enough, though I'm using a rather larger timeout.

So a while after I got that work around in place, I went back and looked at what's going on inside the QFtp itself. Using the debugger to add a print command on a breakpoint I can see the raw replies from the. What seems to be happening is that the ftp server I'm using is sending its ftp replies in a different order sometime.

When it works I my trace looks like:

```
FtpWidget::commandStarted(id: 265) --  Get
Function: QFtpPrivate::_q_piFtpReply(int, const QString &), code: 200, text "Operation successful"
Function: QFtpPrivate::_q_piFtpReply(int, const QString &), code: 213, text "135980"
Function: QFtpPrivate::_q_piFtpReply(int, const QString &), code: 200, text "Operation successful"
Function: QFtpPrivate::_q_piFtpReply(int, const QString &), code: 150, text "Opening BINARY connection for 000-23Sep2014_103527.jpg (135980 bytes)"
Function: QFtpPrivate::_q_piFtpReply(int, const QString &), code: 226, text "Operation successful"
FtpWidget::commandFinished(id: 265, error: 0) -- Get
```

Where the `FtpWidget::commandStarted` and `commandFinished` are my slots, and the _q_piFtpReply() is a private part of the QFtp object where I've hook my tracing breakpoint.

When it fails I get:

```
FtpWidget::commandStarted(id: 256) --  Get
Function: QFtpPrivate::_q_piFtpReply(int, const QString &), code: 200, text "Operation successful"
Function: QFtpPrivate::_q_piFtpReply(int, const QString &), code: 213, text "135896"
Function: QFtpPrivate::_q_piFtpReply(int, const QString &), code: 200, text "Operation successful"
Function: QFtpPrivate::_q_piFtpReply(int, const QString &), code: 150, text "Opening BINARY connection for 000-23Sep2014_103525.jpg (135896 bytes)"
FtpWidget::lostFinshedHack()
FtpWidget::lostFinshedHack() -- file: C:/Users/sean/Temp/Snapshots5/000-23Sep2014_103525.jpg
FtpWidget::connect("ftp://root@169.254.1.180/")
```

Getting the 150 reply code after the 200 reply code seems to be the problem. So if you go look up the FTP reply [codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes) and look through the qftp.cpp it looks having the 150 arrive after the 150 is causing the qftp implementation state machine to go into a perpetual wait. As far as I can tell its my ftp server that is messing things up not the qftp.cpp (maybe I should try wire shark to make sure).

For now I'm sticking to my timeout workaround for the problem.

Comment: I myself tried to hack it through, but I didn't get anything reliable enough. I tried to reconnect when failing but in the end I ended with a lot of simultaneous connections on the ftp server that can't be closed by me. So I decided to give up definetly on using Qt for my FTP operations.

I used instead [FTP Client Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8667/FTP-Client-Class) which is very easy to use AND is reliable.

Answer (score 2):

I am too late to reply, but it still may help others.

In `void Ftp::commandFinished(int i, bool error)` it is always better to check for `QFtp::None` option also,
since if your last command is `get` and when `commandFinished()` slot gets called then 
`if (ftp->currentCommand() == QFtp::Get)` will not be able to identify the last command, since your current command may not be `get` because it is already finished.

You can also check with id
as `if(ftp->currentCommand() == QFtp::Get || 1 == id)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I no longer have access to the problematic code now so I can't test your suggestion, I hope it is going to be helpful for others!